# Make apt-get update and upgrade automate and unattended

Tags: apt

I have about 7 Debian servers I manage, and I would like to set them to automatically update themselves. So, I created a script as such:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

and placed it on the `root`'s crontab list. Unfortunately, it always hangs on the Upgrade section, asking if I'm sure I want to upgrade. Because it's a cron job, I don't see the output until it emails me saying it's failed. Is there a way to have it skip that prompt, and just do the upgrade automatically?

Comment: ... or cron-apt.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use the -y option to apt-get to have it not ask. From `man apt-get`:

```
   -y, --yes, --assume-yes
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```

You can also set the DEBIAN_FRONTEND env variable

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y upgrade
```

Comment: What does `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` do? Is it used for other processes as well?

Comment: I'm trying this on my home server, and will choose the best answer as soon as it runs

Comment: @CanadianLuke see [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/debconf.7.html) for `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`. It's not mentioned in my Debian's `man debconf` though, so it may be an Ubuntu thing.

Comment: @terdon you don't have the -doc package for debconf. It's in the 7 section of the man `man 7 debconf` ;)

Comment: @Braiam ah, OK, I saw that and tried `man 7 debconf` but got nothing. Now I know why :)

Comment: @terdon thanks for the edit, you really improved the answer :-D

Comment: I tend to run a `apt-get dist-upgrade -dy` first. (I actually do not run a upgrade / dist-upgrade itself automatically, it seems risky...) That would pre-download all the packages which at least make installing them faster...

Comment: @CanadianLuke I could no longer find the reference for `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` on the link above, but it's quoted in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/972528/628938).

Comment: Running Ubuntu, and without `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` I was still getting prompted, even with `-y`, so it seems to be required.

Comment: Even with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` and `-y` I got prompted about which services to restart; the same prompt that got me searching for an unattended solution. Upvoted this answer, but the search continues...

Answer (score 39):

Well, maybe you are using the wrong tool. `unattended-upgrades` package installs security upgrades in daily basis (can be configured), you can configure what packages to upgrade or not upgrade, etc. Can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

From `man unattended-upgrades`:

> The configuration is done via  the  apt  configuration  mechanism.  The
>          default  configuration file can be found at /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

Comment: @CanadianLuke it reads all the configurations in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` but only those starting with `Unattended-Upgrade::` get parsed.

Comment: I am trying this on one of the servers at work, and will choose the best answer as soon as it runs

Comment: Since this was not selected as the best answer, I assume the update is still running seven years later. ;)

Answer (score 20):

while the previous answers are informative they don't circumvent the issue of input required by human means during `upgrade`. therefore, i am using the following:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical
sudo -E apt-get -qy update
sudo -E apt-get -qy -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold" upgrade
sudo -E apt-get -qy autoclean
```

to include 'distribution' upgrades like kernels use the `dist-upgrade` command.

please see the [manpgage of `dpkg`](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/dpkg/dpkg.1.en.html) for in-depth information on these parameters.

**important note**: calling `sudo` including the [`-E`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.21/sudo.man.html%20%60-E%60) parameter is required:

`Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.`

otherwise, the `EXPORT` statements will not affect the calls of `apt-get`!

credit goes to [Remy van Elst](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Silent-automatic-apt-get-upgrade.html)! thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why you added the other options to apt-get upgrade?

Comment: Also, is "sudo -E" required if the script is run from rott's crontab?

Comment: @FarO that depends on what environment/in which context you would like the cronjob to run. generally, these are run by `root` - so you do not need to use `sudo` at all.
the 'other options' are set to run unattended in any case. please see the referenced `man`page.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, using `Dpkg::Options` alone didn't work. (My script is already run with sudo so I didn't include `sudo -E`.)

Answer (score 4):

A generic tool for this kind of thing is `yes`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.
```

So, for example, you could do

```
yes | sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Please note that in the specific case of `apt-get upgrade` using the options suggested by [@Braiam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107198/22222) or [@ArthurUlfeldt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107197/22222) is better.

Comment: The line I paste when I want to do it manually is `apt-get update && yes | apt-get upgrade` (our servers aren't supposed to use `sudo`... Don't ask...)

Comment: Why using a trick instead of an option already provided?? "-y" is in apt-get already.

Comment: Because, as I said in the answer, this is a _generic_ tool for this sort of operation, so this answer is for other cases, not for apt. Did you not read the last paragraph? Or the first sentence?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Does this also work as a cron-job? I made a cronjob which should run every day at 00:00. I want both the update and upgrade to always be "yes" if permission is needed.

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder I haven't gone through that path for quite a long time. I am now automating with Ansible.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Understandable. Thanks for the response (and happy christmas)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a post by @diegocn in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27988), I found this command to disable interactiveness:

```
echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

> `debconf-set-selections` can be used to pre-seed the debconf database with answers, or to change answers in the database. Each question will be marked as seen to prevent debconf from asking the question interactively.

> **WARNING**
>
> Only use this command to seed debconf values for packages that will be or are installed. Otherwise you can end up with values in the database for uninstalled packages that will not go away, or with worse problems involving shared values. It is recommended that this only be used to seed the database if the originating machine has an identical install.

[Debian manpage for `debconf-set-selections`.](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/debconf/debconf-set-selections.1.en.html)