# Update / upgrade Debian and skip any interactions

Tags: shell-script, debian, xorg, upgrade, raspbian

I'm running a tiny script to update and upgrade some Debian machines but since some weeks it always stopped due to some "news" the terminal is showing up. When manually upgrading I see a "fullscreen" (find screenshot below) from some software, which forces to press "q". I don't want to change any software so I'd like to find a solution, which allows to just skip every interactive screen, while upgrading.

Usually I was fine using:

```
sudo apt-get update -y 
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

After I realised that the upgrade process is interrupted without any timeout, I also tried to use the solution of this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107194/make-apt-get-update-and-upgrade-automate-and-unattended):

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y upgrade
```

but unfortunately with the same result. Does anybody have a solution to just upgrade a machine without any interruptions?

[image: xorg-server, press q to quit]

**UPDATE**:

First I just executed:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

Secondary edited the /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg file to:

```
# dpkg configuration file
#
# This file can contain default options for dpkg.  All command-line
# options are allowed.  Values can be specified by putting them after
# the option, separated by whitespace and/or an `=' sign.
#

# Do not enable debsig-verify by default; since the distribution is not using
# embedded signatures, debsig-verify would reject all packages.
no-debsig

# Log status changes and actions to a file.
log /var/log/dpkg.log

force-confold
force-confdef
```

Finally I executed:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -yq
```

This did the trick regarding "press q to quit" - **great!**

I think it's also working to combine the commands executing:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew --force-confdef" --force-yes -yq upgrade
```

Unfortunately another similar problem shows up now:

[image]

Also trying to edit */etc/apt/listchanges.conf* didn't work out unfortunately:

```
[apt]
frontend=none
email_address=root
confirm=0
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=news
```

**SOLUTION**:

I noticed (sorry if this is obvious for an advanced linux user) that bash acts different, when you execute a command via script than directly entering the command into the console.

All in all it was enough for my script solution to add the *-yp* parameter and set the *DEBIAN_FRONTEND*. In order to be safe, I'd edit the */etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg* file too.

```
#!/bin/bash
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND
apt-get -yq update
apt-get -yq upgrade
```

Comment: The changes to `listchanges.conf` *did* work out, you're not seeing the changes any more. The `rpi-chromium-mods` screen is something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`, this will stop debconf prompts from appearing.

After that, add  `force-confold` and `force-confdef` to your `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg` file.
then use the `-y` option

```
sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

or use this command

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew --force-confdef" --force-yes -y upgrade
```

and if it doesn't work try

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" --force-yes -y upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed the dpkg.cfg file and set DEBIAN_FRONTEND to non interactive but unfortunately with no success. Also the other commands didn't work for me. Do I get this right to just append dpkg.cfg with the lines _force-confdef_ and _force-confold_ ? The "q to quit" message just keeps popping up.

Comment: try adding the q flag `sudo apt-get upgrade -yq`

Comment: Thanks that worked out for the first problem but another one shows up. Do you have a suggestion for the new one?

Answer (score 1):

The update information is given by `apt-listchanges`. If you never want to see these details, you can remove the package entirely. Otherwise, you can configure it using `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf`; in your case,

```
frontend=mail
```

or

```
frontend=none
```

will avoid the installation being interrupted.

(`apt-listchanges` is supposed to do the right thing in these circumstances, so it should be possible to fix it in other ways so that it still shows update details in interactive mode. In particular you could try adding the `-q` option to `apt-get`.)

Note that simply running

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

won't change anything, you need to ensure it ends up in the environment of the `apt-get` processes:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the _-q_ command worked! I tried editing it to _none_ but a similar problem shows up, I updated the post. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `frontend=none` only affects `apt-listchanges`. The `rpi-chromium-mods` screen you're getting is shown by the `rpi-chromium-mods` package (so I take it you're actually running Raspbian, is that correct?).

Comment: You also need to export `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`.

Comment: Yes right, I'm running Raspbian, I thought that this might be the problem too but I exported it by just typing `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. Might there be a problem because I export the frontend using the pi user but upgrading via sudo?

Comment: No, just typing `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` **doesn't** export the variable, you need to run `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND` afterwards.

Comment: Right, I run 1. `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`, 2. `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND` 3. `sudo apt-get upgrade -yq` but get the pi-chromium-mods configuration box. I don't understand why it's still showing the interaction, although I set it to noninteractive.

Comment: So that's a bug in `rpi-chromium-mods` then.